# Scoping Serilog context via `LogContext.PushProperty` for long running async operations

Tags: serilog

Can anyone provide some insights into why the following works? Odd question - I know.

When the below code runs, two logs are eventually produced, each with a `UUID` property attached with the value `First ID`. I don't understand why this works because the property enricher that's setup in `LogContext.PushProperty` (i.e. `ContextStackBookmark`) is disposed before the second log message is written.

Don't get me wrong, what I observed is definitely the behavior I'm looking for; however, I was expecting to see two log messages: the first with the `UUID` property and the second without.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("UUID", "First ID"))
        {
            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Starting task");
                await Task.Delay(10_000);
                _logger.LogInformation("Finished task");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic is in [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-7.0) - it is similar to thread-local variables with an important difference that it *'flows' down to children tasks*, regardless of when or on which thread they run on.

The details are explain here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html. An important hint/note for the next part in Serilog is also present:

> Because the [copied] references are shared, it’s important not to mutate any values retrieved from the logical call context. If you need to change a logical call context value, update the actual value using CallContext.LogicalSetData. *You should only use immutable types as logical call context data values*.

And the [EncricherStack](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Context/EnricherStack.cs) is precisely that. A [small immutable linked-list implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/).

Thus the Task will inherit the parent's 'enricher stack' at the time the task was *started*, and later re-assignments in the parent will not affect the AsyncLocal value seen inside the task's own context. (The async-await model returns a *started* a task immediately, even if it may not run until later.)

This later re-assignment in this case is in [ContextStackBookmark.Dispose](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs#L177).

```
   public void Dispose()
   {
       // Re-assigns the AsyncLocal value in the parent,
       // without affecting any previous enricher stack already
       // present on the child task contexts.
       Enrichers = _bookmark;
   }
```